# Spring App Not Connecting to Kafka with SSL

Tags: spring, ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I have a Spring boot app with a very simple kafka producer. Everything works great if I connect to a kafka cluster without encryption. But times out if I try to connect to a kafka cluster with SSL. Is there some other configuration I need in the producer or some other property I need to define to allow spring to correctly use all of the configurations?

I have the following properties set:

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=broker1.kafka.poc.com:9093,broker3.kafka.poc.com:9093,broker4.kafka.poc.com:9093,broker5.kafka.poc.com:9093
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-type=jks
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-location=file:/home/ec2-user/truststore.jks
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-password=test1234
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=file:/home/ec2-user/keystore.jks
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-password=test1234
logging.level.org.apache.kafka=debug
server.ssl.key-password=test1234
spring.kafka.ssl.key-password=test1234
spring.kafka.producer.client-id=sym
spring.kafka.admin.ssl.protocol=ssl
```

With the following result printing as the ProducerConfig when the app starts up:

```
o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values:
acks = 1
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = [broker1.kafka.allypoc.com:9093, broker3.kafka.allypoc.com:9093, broker4.kafka.allypoc.com:9093, broker5.kafka.allypoc.com:9093]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.dns.lookup = default
client.id = sym
compression.type = none
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
enable.idempotence = false
interceptor.classes = []
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
linger.ms = 0
max.block.ms = 60000
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
max.request.size = 1048576
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 2147483647
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.key.password = [hidden]
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = /home/ec2-user/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
ssl.keystore.type = jks
ssl.protocol = ssl
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = /home/ec2-user/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
transactional.id = null
value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

My producer is extremely simple:

```
@Service
public class Producer {
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public Producer(KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    void sendMessage(String topic, String message) {
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
    }

    void sendMessage(String topic, String key, String message) {
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, message);
    }
}
```

Connecting to kafka with SSL gets a TimeoutException saying `Topic symbols not present in metadata after 60000 ms.`
If I turn on debug logs, I get this repeatedly, looping all of my brokers.

```
2019-05-29 20:10:25.768 DEBUG 1381 --- [rk-thread | sym] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=sym] Completed connection to node -4. Fetching API versions.
2019-05-29 20:10:25.768 DEBUG 1381 --- [rk-thread | sym] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=sym] Initiating API versions fetch from node -4.
2019-05-29 20:10:25.768 DEBUG 1381 --- [rk-thread | sym] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=sym] Initialize connection to node 10.25.77.13:9093 (id: -3 rack: null) for sending metadata request
2019-05-29 20:10:25.768 DEBUG 1381 --- [rk-thread | sym] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=sym] Initiating connection to node 10.25.77.13:9093 (id: -3 rack: null) using address /10.25.77.13
2019-05-29 20:10:25.994 DEBUG 1381 --- [rk-thread | sym] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node--3.bytes-sent
2019-05-29 20:10:25.996 DEBUG 1381 --- [rk-thread | sym] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node--3.bytes-received
2019-05-29 20:10:25.997 DEBUG 1381 --- [rk-thread | sym] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics  : Added sensor with name node--3.latency
2019-05-29 20:10:25.998 DEBUG 1381 --- [rk-thread | sym] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [Producer clientId=sym] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -3
2019-05-29 20:10:26.107 DEBUG 1381 --- [rk-thread | sym] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [Producer clientId=sym] Connection with /10.25.75.151 disconnected

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:119) ~[kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:381) ~[kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:342) ~[kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:609) ~[kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:541) ~[kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:467) ~[kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:535) ~[kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:311) ~[kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:235) ~[kafka-clients-2.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]

2019-05-29 20:10:26.108 DEBUG 1381 --- [rk-thread | sym] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=sym] Node -1 disconnected.
2019-05-29 20:10:26.110 DEBUG 1381 --- [rk-thread | sym] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=sym] Completed connection to node -3. Fetching API versions.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In producer config security.protocol should be set to SSL. You could also try setting ssl.endpoint.identification.algirithm = "" to disable hostname validation of the certificate in case that's the issue. Other than that, would be useful to see the Kafka broker config.

Comment: yep, security protocol was it. Have to set it with `spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol` not with `spring.kafka.ssl.protocol=` .  Thanks for the help!